# Calling a web service: what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I have the following code for consuming a service that is not working for me.  Can anyone suggest what I can do to narrow down whats going wrong?  I know this is vague so please tell me what you require to provide any suggestions.

The address is: http://localhost:57667/ExampleService.svc/

When visiting directly I get the 'You have created a service... message'

The code that goes wrong is here.  It causes the following error:

```
_url = "http://localhost:57667/ExampleService.svc";
TextReader textReader = new StringReader(HttpPostClient.Post(new Uri(_url), bodyData.ToString(), _exampleServiceRequestEncoding,     Properties.Settings.Default.HttpPostClientExampleAvailabilityTimeout));
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
When visiting this URL directly: http://localhost:57667/ExampleService.svc/ProcessRequest

```
The exception message is 'No component for key example.ExternalWebServiceStubs.Example.ExampleService was found'. 
Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.get_Item(String key) at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WindsorInstanceProvider.GetInstance
```

many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since troubleshooting wcf services will be lot more easier when you provide web.config element also at service side.

My general guess here is, all the wcf services by default uses wsHttpBinding which will not allow direct calling of service like an asmx service we do.

You can replace wsHttpBinding with basicHttpBinding and disable the security to your service in order to get the service work like you are expecting.

Please add some more details about ExampleService.svc binding and it will help you get this resolved fast

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

The normal practice would be to create a proxy class via svcutil.exe (visual studio command prompt) or "add service reference" to consume the service, and then for you to use the methods of your proxy class to call your service's methods.

This tutorial should help (it's based on Visual Studio 2005, you didn't say what version you were using, but you should get a good grounding)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic6